# what is the official/active home of the MercurialEclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I'm having trouble finding the official home of the MercurialEclipse plugin (is there one?), and I have a weird feeling there are actually multiple projects by this name.

Here are some of the projects I've found:

- http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mercurialeclipse/
- http://www.javaforge.com/project/HGE
- http://www.intland.com/products/mercurialeclipse/overview/
- https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/Home

See also this ticket I filed: http://www.javaforge.com/issue/23290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Intland Software (owners of JavaForge) are developing and maintaining the plugin, the official web site is http://www.intland.com/products/mercurialeclipse/overview/, and their official project page http://www.javaforge.com/project/HGE.

The BitBucket page stems from the time when the plugin was developed by Vectrace, but they transferred the project maintenance to Intland, so it’s no longer relevant.

Regarding the Google Code page, see http://www.jroller.com/andyl/entry/how_open_is_mercurialeclipse — At some point in time Intland started requiring a login to JavaForge to use the plugin, which provoked a let’s say... vivid response. However they reverted this behaviour quickly, and as Intland has contributed so much to the project, I forgive them. Before they jumped in, the project had stagnated. In the meanwhile one of the original Vectrace developers of the project created this Google Code project though. If you are sympathetic to that, I guess you could consider the Google Code project the official repository.

Answer (score 7):

It appears the home has moved back to bitbucket.
https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main

At least that is where active bugs/feature_requests are supposed to be filed, according to this note.

[New project home on Bitbucket](http://www.javaforge.com/proj/forum/viewMessage.do?thread_id=79914)

Furthermore, as of today (9/20/12):

1. javaforge is at MercurialEclipse 1.9.1
2. bitbucket is at MercurialEclipse 2.0

The MercurialEclipse 2.0 version has shifted to using JavaHg for its mercurial interactions.

Answer (score 1):

The google code one should be the official home.
However to install it the official update site is :

```
http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable
```

Comment: i suspect that's correct, since it has current artifacts.  but do you know why i got a response on the javaforge site?  just someone being nice and keeping up with the old location?

Comment: maybe a little of mess ... :)

Comment: i reposted my issue to http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mercurialeclipse/issues/detail?id=30 and will accept your answer when the committers acknowledge it, to verify that the project is active ^_^;

Answer (score 0):

Gone restricted again at intland:

> www.intland.com/products/mercurialeclipse/overview/
>
> www.intland.com/products/other-products/

Their codebeamer tracker and repo is stuck on 1.9.1:

> www.javaforge.com/project/HGE

So i guess, bye bye javaforge.

Both code.google.com and bitbucket.org projects have code and are accepting issues.

> code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mercurialeclipse/
>
> bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/overview

Of these, bitbucket seems to be more up to date.

They mention however the same URL for eclipse installer:

> http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable