# eclipse mercurial plugin installation error

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-plugin, installation

I'm trying to install the eclipse mercurial plugin (with eclipse indigo), but I get an error during installation.
I went to help->install new software, then I wrote 'http://cbes.javaforge.com/update - http://cbes.javaforge.com/update' and then checked mercurialEclipse and clicked next. Then I unchecked Windows binaries for Mercurial (I'm on Linux) and clicked 'next'. Then 'next' again. Afterwards, there is a page resuming the license of the software. There are two licenses: "eclipse foundation software user agreement" and "eclipse public license v1.0". The radio button is set by default to "I do no accept the terms of the license", and if I switch it to "I accept the terms of the license agreements", both of the licenses are automatically set to "I accept the terms of the license agreements".

My problem is that, even after I click on "I accept the terms of the license agreements", the "next" button remains grey, and hence I can't proceed to the installation of my plugin.

Is that a bug ? Is there a work around ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try [the update URL from the Google Code repository](http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable) instead? If your next question is "Why do we have two update URLs?" there's [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764062/what-is-the-official-active-home-of-the-mercurialeclipse-plugin) hereabouts that should help answer your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I did try that, but I get the same error as well. Even though I agreed to the license terms, I can't click next.

Comment: I decided to try this again just to make sure; I presume you selected MercurialEclipse version 1.9.4.201203270141 and then clicked on Next, which takes you to "Review Licenses"; I now see your problem: once you accept the terms of the license agreement, The Next button remains grey; However the Finish button is enabled and this is what you should click (perhaps the Next button is grey simply because there is no additional step that requires input from you). Can you try this out and see if you get further?

Comment: Oh right thanks. I don't think the other link had that, or maybe they just corrected it in the meantime, after I mentioned it on their site. Or maybe I was just blind. In either case, it works now, thanks a lot.