# MercurialEclipse - Show History not working

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

My Team --> Show History has never worked for Mercurial Eclipse, and I'm finally getting around to trying to fix it.

I've tried searching for a solution, but all I can find are some old 2009 posts for what seemed like a temporary problem. I've tried starting Eclipse with the -clean option (as suggested in the old posts) with no luck. My Decorations are enabled for Mercurial.

I've been getting by this long because Compare With --> Another Revision works, but only with the revision on HEAD per branch.

Also, if I go to Preferences --> Team --> Mercurial --> Performance and enable "Show changeset information for files (very slow)", I am able to see the last change date next to individual files for the repository.

Mercurial Eclipse version 2.0.0.v201210091230

Intland Software com.intland.hgbinary.win32 version 2.3.2

Eclipse Helios

I'm working on an Android project if that makes any difference.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Nothing is outputted in the Mercurial Console when I select Show History. The Mercurial Console does receive output when doing a compare to another revision though.

Comment: I should probably add that I have some old SVN and CVS eclipse plugins installed that I haven't used in ages. Maybe there's some conflict going on? I've checked both of their Consoles, but neither of them show anything.

Comment: Doing `Team --> Refresh` on the file before doing `Team --> Show History` makes it work for me. Not sure if it's the same problem as you though.

Comment: Try view history from command line to be sure that your repository is ok. It's possible that Eclipse throws a clue in log files.

Comment: @David - Nope, that didn't fix it. I did just notice something though. I had my History view populated with the Local History already, and when I tested Show History, the previous Local History remained. It seems like even though the History view is focused when selecting Show History, the actual call isn't being made.

Comment: @angelcerva, the command line log check worked. Interesting.

Comment: Two things I just noticed. In the History view, if I enable Link with Editor and Selection, I get the following error: "An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Could not initialize class com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse.history.MercurialHistoryPage"

Comment: When I tried seeing if I somehow didn't pick up a dependency for the plugin, I noticed that on the Eclipse Marketplace, there are 2 MercurialEclipse versions available: "Mercurial Eclipse by MercurialEclipse Project, EPL" and what I have installed: "MercurialEclipse (was: HgEclipse) by Intland Software, EPL". I guess I'll try the other plugin, though it seems like it's from the same people but was re-branded or something.

Comment: @DavidLevesque: doing team->refresh makes history work. Thanks!

Comment: @user443854 Great, I added it as an answer in case it is useful for other people as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by installing "Mercurial Eclipse by MercurialEclipse Project, EPL" as listed in the EclipseMarketplace.

I had "MercurialEclipse (was: HgEclipse) by Intland Software, EPL" installed, which was a version from before HgEclipse rebranded to MercurialEclipse. Even though I had installed using the instruction found at http://javaforge.com/project/HGE#download to Install New Software: http://cbes.javaforge.com/update, it seems that didn't install/update properly. When I used the EclipseMarketplace and installed the "Mercurial Eclipse by MercurialEclipse Project, EPL" plugin version, it claimed I already had it installed, but updated anyway, and that fixed the problem.

Comment: The home of MercurialEclipse is not on JavaForge any more. It is https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236436/whats-the-relationship-between-the-two-mercurialeclipse-plugin-sites?rq=1

Comment: Ahh, I see. I simply went with the first result from a Google search of "Mercurial Eclipse", which is still the JavaForge page.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `Team --> Refresh` on the file before doing `Team --> Show History` seems to make it work in some cases.